# How to get text value from radio button and assign value to a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I am using one text box and 3 div, how can I set the entered value in that div?
Here is my code. I have to get the div value from the radio button selected. Likewise, how can I get the text box value?

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#radio_submit").click(function(e) {
    var check = $("input[name=user_options]:checked").parent().next().text();
    if (!check) {
      alert('Please select options!');
    } else {
      $('#valueee').html(check);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <div>Choose option:</div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="user_options" value="456" />
  </div>
  <div name="deff" id="val1" x>123</div>
  <span>CSS</span>
  <br></br>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="user_options" value="456" />
  </div>
  <div name="deff" id="val2">456</div>
  <span>html</span>
  <br></br>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="user_options" value="678" />
  </div>
  <div name="deff" id="val3">678</div>
  <span>jquery</span>
  <br></br>

  <div name="deff" id="val4">
    <input type="radio" name="user_options" value="675" />
  </div>
  <input class="text-input" id="other-input" size="5" value="">
  <span>JS</span>
  <br></br>


  <div><button id="radio_submit" type="button">Show Selected Radio</button></div>
</form>
<div id="valueee"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your meaning but may be you need to again check and try to get **`val()`** if is **`undefined`**,

#### View Demo <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hu5mt4s/)</kbd>

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#radio_submit").click(function (e) {
        var check = $("input[name=user_options]:checked").parent().next().text();
        if (!check) var check = $("input[name=user_options]:checked").parent().next().val();
        if (!check) {
            alert('Please select options!');
        } else {
            $('#valueee').html(check);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
    <div>Choose option:</div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="user_options" value="456" />
    </div>
    <div name="deff" id="val1" x>123</div>
    <span>CSS</span>

    <br></br>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="user_options" value="456" />
    </div>
    <div name="deff" id="val2">456</div>
    <span>html</span>

    <br></br>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="user_options" value="678" />
    </div>
    <div name="deff" id="val3">678</div>
    <span>jquery</span>

    <br></br>
    <div name="deff" id="val4">
        <input type="radio" name="user_options" value="675" />
    </div>
    <input class="text-input" id="other-input" size="5" value="" />
    <span>JS</span>

    <br></br>
    <div>
        <button id="radio_submit" type="button">Show Selected Radio</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="valueee"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is()` to check if next element is `div` or `input`. If `input` then use `.val()` to read value otherwise use `.text()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#radio_submit").click(function (e) {
     var next = $("input[name=user_options]:checked").parent().next();
     //check if next element is input and read value otherwise read text         
     var check = '';
     if($(next).is('input'))
         check = $(next).val();
     else
         check = $(next).text();

     if(!check){
          alert('Please select options!');
     }else{
          $('#valueee').html(check);  
     }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ebLdawh6/3/)**